# React prop value not updating in object initialization during re render

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have a component that creates a configuration object during render. The configuration object relies on a value that's passed in as a prop. When the prop changes, I want the value inside of the configuration object to update. Here is what the component looks like:

```
export const LeaseEditor = ({ onChange, leaseDocument, save, rentTableData }: any) => {
  // rentTableData is the prop that will change
  console.log(rentTableData) // this shows the correct values when the prop changes

  const config = {
    ...
    rentTable: {
      rentTableRenderer: (domElement: any) => {
        console.log('rentTableData in method', rentTableData) // when the prop changes, this value is not updated, it logs the previous value when this is invoked
        ReactDOM.render(<RentTablePreview values={rentTableData} />, domElement)
      },
    },
  }

  return (
    <div className="lease-editor">
      <div className="lease-editor__toolbar" ref={toolbarElem}></div>

      <div className="lease-editor__editable-container">
        {leaseDocument.body && rentTableData && (
          <CKEditor
            editor={Editor}
            isReadOnly={false}
            config={config} // config object feeds in fine during the first render
            data={leaseDocument.body}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

when `rentTableData` is updated, the value is logged correctly in the component, but when the method is invoked from the config it uses the previous value (what the prop was during first render).

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with CKEditor, but it probably does not take changes to the `config` prop into account, which would explain the stale values. You could use `useRef` ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)) to get `rentTableRenderer` to use the current value of `rentTableData`.

Just add a new constant `rentTableDataRef` and replace `rentTableData` in the body of the arrow function with `rentTableData.current`:

```
export const LeaseEditor = ({ onChange, leaseDocument, save, rentTableData }: any) => {
  // rentTableData is the prop that will change
  console.log(rentTableData) // this shows the correct values when the prop changes
  const rentTableDataRef = useRef(rentTableData)

  const config = {
    ...
    rentTable: {
      rentTableRenderer: (domElement: any) => {
        console.log('rentTableData in method', rentTableDataRef.current)
        ReactDOM.render(<RentTablePreview values={rentTableDataRef.current} />, domElement)
      },
    },
  }
```

Comment: Not too familiar with ref's but with the code you provided `rentTableDataRef.current` is null for me. Is it due to the prop value being null during the first render?

Comment: Following up on this, I used a `useEffect` to update the ref manually when the prop changes and it fixed my issue. Thanks a ton for this, been struggling for hours!